# How to setup Dnscrypt with a DNS cache service?

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq, dnscrypt-proxy

I wanted to setup dnscrypt but the [dnscrypt-proxy manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/dnscrypt-proxy.8.html) says I shouldn't run it *without* a dns cache service like dnsmasq or unbound. As far as I know Ubuntu doesn't have a working dns cache service. So how do I proceed from here? Should I install unbound?

I tried installing dnscrypt-proxy from universe repo and it works fine. But the internet kinda feels slow. Maybe it's because of the warning about using dnscrypt without any dns cache?

The only detailed guide I found about setting up dnscrypt+unbound is in Arch Wiki. Please guide me in Setting up Dnscrypt with a dns cache service.

Comment: `dnscrypt-proxy` version 2 apparently does have caching.